# Force TypeScript to infer constant values instead of string

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to force TypeScript to infer type as specific values passed into function, not a general type?

```
function infer<T>(...args: T[]): T[] {
   return args;
}

const numbers = infer('one', 'two'); // Inferred type of numbers: string[]
                                     // Desired type of numbers: ('one' | 'two')[]
```

I know I can achieve desired type by writing `infer<'one' | 'two'>('one', 'two')` but I'd like to not repeat myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types):

```js
function infer<T extends string, A extends T[]>(...args: [...A]) {
   return args;
}

const numbers = infer('one', 'two'); // ["one", "two"]
```

OR just provide appropriate constraint:

```js
function infer<T extends string>(...args:T[]) {
   return args;
}

const numbers = infer('one', 'two'); // ("one" | "two")[]
```

If you want to lear more about inference on functionarguments you can check my [article](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments)
I have described most popular questions about inference

Comment: Thanks! I need infer function to handle not just strings, but it was easy to add special support for strings with overloading:
`function infer<T extends string>(...args:T[]): T[]; function infer<T>(...args:T[]): T[] {...}`
`